# International driving permit

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

I am a British passport holder living in India since one and half year.We planned UK holidays, done all the bookings only to realise that my UK driving license is overdue for renewal. I can't renew it any more as I am not a UK resident. I can't get international driving permit from India as I am an OCI card holder.
I called British embassy here but they don't deal with such matter. I need to rent a car in the UK...what should I do

Comment: I called up the UK car Rental companies, they require International driving permit along with Indian driving license.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Indian driving licence, then you can rent a car in the UK using that - assuming that the Indian Licence has English language on it to declare who you are and what driving entitlement you have.

I have done exactly this with my Thai driving licence because my UK licence similarly expired years ago. I got an International Driving Permit in Bangkok in anticipation of being asked to produce it when hiring a car. The girl at the car hire place said there was no need, as my Thai licence also has English on it.